# Find the nth element in vue-test-utils

Tags: css, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm using vue-test-utils with jest.
My wrapper contains 9 input elements an I'd like to get the third one.
This solution works:

```
    wrapper.findAll('input').at(3) // OK
```

According to documentation (https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/selectors.html), I should be able to use CSS pseudo selectors, but this does not work:

```
    wrapper.find('input:nth-of-type(3)') // ErrorWrapper
```

With this method, I can only get the first input:

```
    wrapper.find('input:nth-of-type(1)') // OK
```

Am I misusing the CSS selector?

My wrapper HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="layout wrap">
   <div class="flex xs12 sm12 md12" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!----> <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="v-input v-text-field theme--light">
         <div class="v-input__prepend-outer">
            <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon fa fa-user theme--light"></i></div>
         </div>
         <div class="v-input__control">
            <div class="v-input__slot">
               <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label aria-hidden="true" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Nom*</label><input aria-label="Nom*" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-text-field__details">
               <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                  <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex xs12 sm12 md12" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!----> <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="v-input v-text-field theme--light">
         <div class="v-input__prepend-outer">
            <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon fa fa-user theme--light"></i></div>
         </div>
         <div class="v-input__control">
            <div class="v-input__slot">
               <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label aria-hidden="true" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Prénom*</label><input aria-label="Prénom*" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-text-field__details">
               <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                  <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex xs12 sm12 md12" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!----> <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="v-input v-text-field theme--light">
         <div class="v-input__prepend-outer">
            <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon fa fa-at theme--light"></i></div>
         </div>
         <div class="v-input__control">
            <div class="v-input__slot">
               <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label aria-hidden="true" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Email*</label><input aria-label="Email*" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-text-field__details">
               <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                  <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex xs12 sm12 md12" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!----> <!----> 
      <div>
         <div class="v-menu">
            <div class="v-menu__content theme--light " style="max-height: auto; min-width: 290px; max-width: auto; top: 12px; left: 0px; transform-origin: top left; z-index: 0; display: none;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="v-input v-text-field theme--light">
            <div class="v-input__prepend-outer">
               <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon v-icon--link material-icons theme--light">event</i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-input__control">
               <div class="v-input__slot">
                  <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label aria-hidden="true" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Date de naissance</label><input aria-label="Date de naissance" type="text"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="v-text-field__details">
                  <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                     <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
   <div class="flex xs12 sm12 md12" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!----> <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="v-input v-text-field theme--light">
         <div class="v-input__prepend-outer">
            <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light">place</i></div>
         </div>
         <div class="v-input__control">
            <div class="v-input__slot">
               <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label aria-hidden="true" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Adresse</label><input aria-label="Adresse" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-text-field__details">
               <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                  <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex xs12 sm12 md12" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!----> <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="v-input v-text-field theme--light">
         <div class="v-input__control">
            <div class="v-input__slot">
               <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label aria-hidden="true" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Code postal</label><input aria-label="Code postal" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-text-field__details">
               <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                  <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex xs12 sm12 md12" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!----> <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="v-input v-text-field theme--light">
         <div class="v-input__control">
            <div class="v-input__slot">
               <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label aria-hidden="true" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Ville</label><input aria-label="Ville" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-text-field__details">
               <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                  <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex xs12 sm12 md12" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!----> <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="v-input v-text-field theme--light">
         <div class="v-input__prepend-outer">
            <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light">smartphone</i></div>
         </div>
         <div class="v-input__control">
            <div class="v-input__slot">
               <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label aria-hidden="true" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Numéro de téléphone</label><input aria-label="Numéro de téléphone" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-text-field__details">
               <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                  <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex xs12 sm12 md12" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!----> <!----> <!----> 
      <div class="v-input v-text-field theme--light">
         <div class="v-input__prepend-outer">
            <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon fa fa-globe-europe theme--light"></i></div>
         </div>
         <div class="v-input__control">
            <div class="v-input__slot">
               <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label aria-hidden="true" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Nationalité</label><input aria-label="Nationalité" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-text-field__details">
               <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                  <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to share the HTML markup too in order to be inspected

Comment: I added HTML markup.

Comment: I'm gonna assume `v-messages__wrapper` is your `wrapper`. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The wrapper is a vue-test-utils notion : https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/. It contains the whole HTML

Comment: You're right, I had a wrong understanding of nth-of-type. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason `wrapper.find('input:nth-of-type(3)')` doesn't work is because your inputs aren't siblings with the same parent. And the reason `wrapper.findAll('input').at(3)` works is because it traverses the entire DOM to look for the inputs and create an array from which it fetches the 3rd element